# Is there any use of logarithmic derivatives of modular forms?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Does taking the logarithmic derivative of a modular form have any uses, such as identifying patterns in its coefficients or possible zeros of its corresponding L function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Application 1:  in the chapter on modular forms in Serre's *Course in Arithmetic*, he integrates the logarithmic derivative $f'/f$ of a modular form $f$ on ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$ around a contour (Argument principle) to get an important identity (Theorem $3$) that is used later (Theorem $4$, Corollary $1$) to work out dimensions of spaces of modular forms on ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$. (This is such a standard way to derive those dimensions that I have to ask: how did you see those dimensions worked out if it wasn't by the method used in Serre's book involving logarithmic derivatives?)

Application 2:
We can derive the famous $q$-product of the modular form $\Delta(\tau)$ by working with its logarithmic derivative.

We will need one background fact first. Letting $\mathcal H$ be the upper half-plane,
if $g \colon \mathcal H \rightarrow \mathbf C$ is holomorphic, bounded
at $i\infty$, and satisfies
$$
g(\tau+1) = g(\tau), \ \ \ \ g(-1/\tau) = \tau^2g(\tau) + c\tau
$$
for some constant $c$, then one can show $g(\tau) = (\pi i/6)cE_{2}(\tau)$, where $E_2(\tau) := 1 - 24\sum_{n \geq 1}\sigma(n)e^{2\pi in\tau}$ is the "fake" weight 2 modular form, where $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} d$. By "fake" I mean $E_{2}(\tau+1) = E_{2}(\tau)$ on $\mathcal H$ but
$E_{2}(-1/\tau) \not= \tau^2E_{2}(\tau)$, and instead
$E_{2}(-1/\tau) = \tau^2E_{2}(\tau) + (6/\pi i)\tau$.

**Theorem**. *For $\tau \in \mathcal H$ with* $q = e^{2\pi i\tau}$
$$
\Delta(q) = q\prod_{n \geq 1}(1-q^n)^{24}.
$$

*Proof*. Since $\Delta(\tau)$ is a weight $12$ modular form,
the logarithmic derivative $\Delta'(\tau)/\Delta(\tau)$
satisfies
$$
g(\tau+1) = g(\tau), \ \ \ \ g(-1/\tau) = \tau^2g(\tau) + 12\tau.
$$
Since $\Delta(\tau)$ is nonvanishing, its logarithmic
derivative is holomorphic on  $\mathcal H$.  Moreover,
$\Delta'(\tau)/\Delta(\tau) \rightarrow 2\pi i$ as $\tau \rightarrow i\infty$. Therefore $\Delta'(\tau)/\Delta(\tau) = 2\pi iE_{2}(\tau)$ by the result I described at the start.

Switching variables from $\tau$ to $q = e^{2\pi i\tau}$, $\Delta'(\tau) = 
2\pi iq\Delta'(q)$, where the $'$ represents
differentiation with respect to $\tau$ on the left
and with respect to $q$ on the right. Therefore
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\Delta'(q)}{\Delta(q)} & = & \frac{1}{q}E_{2}(q) \\
& = & \frac{1}{q}\left(1 - 24\sum_{n \geq 1}\sigma(n)q^n\right) \\
& = & \frac{1}{q}\left(1 - 24\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{nq^n}{1-q^n}\right) \\
& = & \frac{1}{q} + 24\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{-nq^{n-1}}{1-q^n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This is the logarithmic derivative of
$q\prod_{n \geq 1}(1-q^n)^{24}$ on $|q| < 1$, where the product
is holomorphic and nonvanishing.
Functions with equal logarithmic derivatives on $|q| < 1$ are equal up to a nonzero scaling factor, so
$\Delta(q) = cq\prod_{n \geq 1}(1-q^n)^{24}$.  Comparing
the coefficient of $q$ in the power series expansion of both sides, $c = 1$.  So we're done.

**Remark**. The $q$-product for $\Delta$ is usually attributed to Jacobi, but it's not really due to him. Details on that are [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5045/jacobis-product-for-the-discriminant).

Comment: Are there any uses of the logarithms of modular forms themselves?
I was able to find an infinite series expression for the logarithm of modular forms which are eta products of weight 12 and was just wondering whether it would be worth further exploring the expression or otherwise

Comment: Your original question asked for any use of *logarithmic derivatives* and I showed you two. Your comment is about something else: uses of the logarithms of modular forms, not logarithmic derivatives. Have you now changed your mind about what you want to ask?

Comment: Apologies for the sudden shift in topic, yes I have. Should I post my querry as a different question?

Comment: Yes, since rewriting a question can have the effect of making past answers lose their meaning to people who see the page later. I also suggest posting such questions on math stackexchange, not here, since they do not seem to be  research level and thus are better suited to MSE than to MO.